# How can I pause the timer control in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, timer

In my program, I would like to pause the timer control in VS2010. I also would like to know if it's possible to get the remaining interval on the timer. (e.g. The timer has been running for 25 seconds and 450 ms, and its interval is 60 seconds; I time remaining before it completes that cycle.) I realize the timer is only accurate to about 55ms or so.

Edit: I realized I could compare start and stop time, and use that to determine the remaining interval. However, if there is a way to directly pull the remaining interval, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: How does this apply to VS2010?

Comment: The `Timer` component (NOT control) does not expose the amount of time since it's last `Tick` or to its next.  You could use a `Stopwatch` that you start, stop and reset in unison, although it will never be synchronised to the ms.

Comment: It applies because I'm using it in VS2010. Granted, you don't need VS to create the Timer. But that's what I'm working with, so I figured I'd tag it. My wordage is off, yeah. I meant to say component.

Ah, I didn't even think about stopwatch. Sure, it won't be synced, but they're started at the same time. They'd be close enough for my purposes.